# I have a problem to allocate memory.(maybe)

Tags: c

There is input file; unsorted long type numbers.(about 1 million)
I want to sort numbers in input files. 
To allocate the memory of array, I used fseek and ftell. 
But segmentation fault is occurred.
How do i fix the code?

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    long *arr;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    FILE *fp2 = NULL;
    int   i = 0;
    long  size, count;

    fp  = fopen( "argv[1]", "r" );
    fp2 = fopen( "sorted",  "w" );
    if ( fp == NULL || fp2 == NULL )
        printf( "error \n" );
    else
    {
        fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
        size = ftell( fp );
        arr = ( long * ) malloc( size );
        count = fread( arr, size, 4, fp );

        Quicksort( arr, 0, sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( int ) - 1 );

        while ( i != ( sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( int ) - 1 ) )
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j;
            for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
                fwrite( arr, size, 1, fp2 );
        }
    }
    fclose( fp );
    free( arr );
    fclose( fp2 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the `long` values in your file are in binary format?

Comment: Your `while` loop never exits.

Comment: I think you mean `fp  = fopen( "argv[1]", "r" );` should be `fp  = fopen( argv[1], "r" );`  (i.e. no quotes).

Comment: `free( arr ); ` you are freeing arr even if fp are NULL

Comment: @Andreas Then how do i fix the code? I want to read all numbers in the file.

Comment: Your `fwrite` has a wrong `size` argument.

Comment: What's that `int i` *inside* your inner lopo?!

Comment: This `sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( int )` won't do what you expect, as `arr` is pointer and *an* an array!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the code is finding the number of bytes in the file with `ftell()`, and then allocating whatever `size` amount that data is.

However, when then reading from the file, it's trying to read four times as much data, because of the *count-of-elements*, and *size-of-elements* passed to `fread()`.

If the input file was a big block of binary longs (in the same format as the local hardware), it's possible to just `fread()` the lot in a single go.  This means your size is the `ftell()` result, but the count-of-elements is **one**.

```
fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
size = ftell( fp );
arr = ( long * ) malloc( size );
count = fread( arr, size, 1, fp );  // read the whole block in a single go
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of issues here and I think this isn’t the actual code even. The ones immediately noticeable:

- you’re trying to open a file called `argv[1]`, not the filename given in command line. Drop the quotes.
- you allocate memory for `size` bytes, then try to read `size * 4` bytes and don’t check how many were read
- don’t cast the return value of `malloc`
- `sizeof arr` only gives you the size of a pointer, not the data you have. You have `size`, use it.
- your while loop has a new variable with the same name as outside, neither is ever changed so the loop is eternal
- if you can’t open a file you free an unassigned pointer

So check your compiler’s warnings. Think about what you’re doing, what the parameters you give to functions mean. Check return values. Use a debugger to step through the code line by line.

The exact cause can only be determined after you fix the other problems, and might even get fixed by that. If this is the exact code then the last one is probably the reason. A debugger will tell you.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of things that needs attention in no particular order of severity

- *always validate arguments*

your program doesn't seem to validate arguments which is kind of bad, a quick statement at the start will do the job

```
 /* Always do some argument checking, Assuming in your case command line is 2 */
    if ( argc != 2 ) 
    {
        printf("Invalid arguments ");
        printf("Usage %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
```

- *always check return values*

Almost always its a good Idea to check for return values and validate them, there are of course some exceptions `printf` for example but cases like `fopen`, `malloc` its a crime to not check for return values

```
/* Return Type Validations are mandatory */
    fp  = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error Opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
```

- *Do not cast malloc result*

This is a popular one [Do I cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the answer is no

- *`fread`*

This probably down to misunderstanding function behavior, from [man fread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html)

```
The function fread() reads nmemb items of data, each size bytes long,
       from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location
       given by ptr.
```

you are essentially reading 4 times the data your need by writing statement like

```
count = fread( arr, size, 4, fp );
```

- *mixing `local` and `global` scopes*

  There are multiple declarations of variable `i` in local ( inside `for loop`) and global scope do not do that.
- *Careful while using `sizeof()` for poniters*

this statement `sizeof( arr )` always gives the size of pointer and not the sizeof data pointed by the pointer, the below statement

```
Quicksort( arr, 0, sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( int ) - 1 );
```

did not make much sense to me, and there is no way I can evaluate if that is really a valid in context of your program.